# Switch on daily chatter notifications for all users

Tags: chatter

We decided that all users should receive daily Chatter digest via Email. Is it possible to turn this on via a mass update of all users, or do users have to turn it on themselves?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Chatter email notification setting for each Chatter group.  Members of a group can set this option, but it can also be set via the CollaborationGroupMember API.  The default should be set to daily.

I don't think that is the daily digest you were referring to though, as there is another daily digest for records the user follows.  I do not know if this can be changed through the API, but I think the default for this is also daily, so if a user doesn't have it set to daily, they would have intentionally changed it.  Please let me know if you aren't seeing it as the default for a user.